# React Native with Redux and React Navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm playing around with Redux with React Native, but I can't get it to work. I am getting an error, saying:

> "TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0, _react.useMemo)')";

I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/jdalri/f1168f3b72244eb4d6d3834a25d52b09) with my React Native project files and the complete error. I can't figure out why this undefined is happening... maybe its because of the navigation configs?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of React Native are you using? It seems like you or some of the packages you installed is using React hooks, but those are available only in the React native version starting from 0.59.

So try to upgrade RN and see if the issue persists.